# Should I include secondary dependencies in my conda environment.yml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Ok, longtime JS dev, psuedo-new Python dev here. I've been using conda for a while in my team's repo, and I'm confused about some dependency behavior. I'm unsure if this is best-practice, but we're including secondary dependencies in our `environment.yml`.

In Node.js land, you obviously don't do this, and Node knows to take care of this (by installing as many copies of each secondary dep as needed), thus the ~8TB `node_modules` everyone has. Conda on the other hand, seems to only allow a single copy of each dep in your `~/opt/pkgs/` (if you're on a Mac, `~/anaconda/pkgs/` on Windows), which really throws a wrench through the windshield if you have different dependencies with hard requirements for certain versions.

So, my main question is: should I include all dependencies I have (top-level, secondary, so on) in my `environment.yml`? What are best practices here?

My second question is why does Conda resolve dependencies this way? Everyone one has massive hard drives, I haven't met a hard drive in the last decade that couldn't handle two different copies of one dependency.

Thanks in advance, any resources/help/opinions/insults are all appreciated.